# populate a drop down menu with database users names, when a username is selected refresh showing users details

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu, view, database-connection

I have made a connection between the drop down menu and the database which shows the current usernames in the rows. I then need to be able to click a box next to the menu that says go and  then for it to redirect or refresh to a page with the selected usernames details.
I really need your help anyone i have been searching the net for weeks trying to find a solution.

Comment: have you tried something from your own?

Comment: if you mean have i tried to make it work, yes i have been trying for a few days and cannot find a way to redirect to the page with the selected users details. no matter what i do i just cant do it!

Comment: Just make it a link to a page that shows users details and add which id to the url eg.  /users.php?id=xxx you can then use $_GET['id'] in your page to find out which user they want

Comment: hi anigel, can you please give me a brief example of this. so i can work off that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

In the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    window.location = '?username='+username;
}
</script>
```

Then your html dropdown and button:

```
<select id="username">
<option value="user">user</option>
<option value="name">name</option>
<option value="list">list</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="go" onclick="showUser()" />
```

With your data coming through from your database, your select field might look like:

```
<select id="username">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff");
while($user = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
    echo '<option value="'.$user->username.'">'.$user->username.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: hi nathan, the problem im having is that the drop down menu is populated with usernames from the database so there is no user, name and list?

Comment: You would replace my options with your populated data. I'll post a quick edit to show you what I mean

Comment: I don't know what your table is called, or your fields. You'll need to post your code that you use that shows how you pull through the rows already

Comment: Table: staff, Fields: username,name and             $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff");

Comment: Please see updated answer. Just FYI, you should be using mysqli_ instead of mysql_ as mysql_, depending on your php version, is/will be deprecated

Comment: i have put it in but still no info?

Comment: Sorry, see my edited answer. I had == instead of = in the while loop. If it works, please don't forget to mark as best answer

Comment: it worked but how do i make it display the info on the page for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Use a form

```
<form action="/yourpage" method="post">
  <select>
    <option value="<?=$id; ?>"><?=$name; $></option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

In yourpage.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
   // load user data
   // or redirect with header() to preexisting page
}
// load view with user data
?>
```

Comment: it wouldn't be bad to have a php backup for if your users have javascript disabled